# Increasing the amount of data sent in a single socket.send() call

Tags: python, pyopenssl

We have code similar to the one below to create an SSL enabled socket between a machine and a remote host to transfer data. We notice that the amount of data sent in each call to sock.send is about 16K. Is there a way to configure this? Send 10 MB of data in 16K chunks is very slow, can we configure the chunk size to about 1-2 MB?

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
import socket

''' Create SSL context.
ctx = ...

''' Create SSL enabled socket.
sock = SSL.Connection(ctx, socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM))

''' Connect to the remote host.
sock.connect((host_address, port))

''' msg is a large string about 10 MB.
msg = ... 

''' Send data over the socket.
total_sent = 0
while (total_sent < len(msg)):
  sent = sock.send(msg[total_sent:])
  total_sent += sent
```

Comment: Please use `#` for single-line comments.  Your use of `'''` makes your code very, very difficult to read.  Also, please run a profiler on your code.  You'll find that the `msg[total_sent:]` is probably the single most expensive part of this loop.

Answer (score 3):

The `send` method doesn't guarantee to send all the bytes, but the `sendall` method does. That will avoid the string slicing.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it can be done, increasing the block size from 16K to 1-2MB will almost certainly have no effect on performance. The likely bottleneck is the throughput of your TCP/IP connection (and the [MTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) of your Ethernet network is probably around 1500 or 9000 bytes, so everything gets chopped up into pieces of that size anyway).

Comment: When we scp a 10 MB file between the two machines it takes less than 10 seconds to transfer the file. When we attempt to tranfer the file using the above code - it takes ages. How is scp able to transfer data at a much faster rate?

Comment: @user1154735: One thing that looks mildly suspect are the repeated calls to `msg[total_sent:]` on a 10MB string. Could you change that to `msg[total_sent:total_send+16*1024]` and try again?

Comment: @aix: Won't help much.  The construction of new strings from old strings will be killer.  The trick here is to avoid creating a new string alltogether.  I think this is an appropriate place for a http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#buffer.

Comment: @S.Lott: With respect, I've benchmarked the two, and there's an almost 400-fold difference in performance. Now, whether that's the actual bottleneck, we don't know.

Comment: @aix: Interesting!  You should provide numbers in your answer, then.